# Label.text is not updating using backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using backgroundworker to shows elapsed time for the loop to compute in order to finished a heavy task inside the loop.

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Stopwatch StopWatch_Summary = new Stopwatch();
        BackgroundWorker xBackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        Label xLabel = new Label();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            xBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            xBackgroundWorker.DoWork += xbackgroundWorker_DoWork;
            xBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += xbackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
            xLabel.Text = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";

            HeavyComputation();
        }

        private void xbackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                xBackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (!StopWatch_Summary.IsRunning)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        private void xbackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan timeSpan = StopWatch_Summary.Elapsed;

            xLabel.Text = String.Format("Time : {0:00}:{1:00} sec", timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);
        }
        private void HeavyComputation()
        {
            StopWatch_Summary.Start();
            xBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

            //for(int i=1;i<=MyX;i++)
            //{
            //Heavy Computation that takes 38seconds to compute
            //}

            StopWatch_Summary.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

I assigned xLabel.Text="XXXXXXXXXXX" in order to check if label is updating. I found out that label remains "XXXXXXXXXXX" during the duration of loop and just update until loop is finished. after roughly 38seconds the xLabel.Text="Time : 00:38 sec". How can i fixed this.

Comment: Isn't this something you can solve by yourself by simply using the debugger together with some breakpoints?

Comment: @Set Not a duplicate, since he already correctly uses the `ProgressChanged` event which is invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: i tried to put breakpoints at "xbackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged" and found out it going there just once.

Comment: xLabel.Update(); right after xLabel.Text = "whatever";

Comment: Are you running the worker just to raise the progress change event ? And doing the work on the UI thread?

Comment: What's the need of that `while (true)`?

Comment: @Rahul to determine if stopwatch is running. if it is running, it will continue to release update.

Comment: @GuidoG .update is not working either

Comment: @Mark yes that is what i need to do. UI is running at the same time progress changed is raised

Comment: @Vincent yes you are right, but look at doerig's answer it will help you

Answer (score 2):

```
xBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

returns immediately and does not wait until the worker has finished 
(because it is Async)

then  StopWatch_Summary.Stop(); is executed and therefore the loop in DoWork is finished after the first iteration

I guess it should look like this (not tested):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Stopwatch StopWatch_Summary = new Stopwatch();
        BackgroundWorker xBackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        Label xLabel = new Label();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            xBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            xBackgroundWorker.DoWork += xbackgroundWorker_DoWork;
            xBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += xbackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
            xLabel.Text = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";

            StartHeavyComputation();
        }

        private void xbackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            StopWatch_Summary.Start();
            xBackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0);

            for(int i=1;i<=MyX;i++)
            {
                xBackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);    
                //Heavy Computation that takes 38seconds to compute
            }

            StopWatch_Summary.Stop();
        }

        private void xbackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan timeSpan = StopWatch_Summary.Elapsed;
            xLabel.Text = String.Format("Time : {0:00}:{1:00} sec", timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);
        }

        private void StartHeavyComputation()
        {
            xBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i fixed that. my procedure is in right order, right? start the stopwatch then the runworkerasync, next my computation and lastly stopping the stopwatch

Comment: @Vincent Please [read the documentation about `BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx). Basically, put your code into `DoWork`, no need to loop or anything.

Comment: as Uwe said, the long running computation code should be put into DoWork, an "infinite" loop is not required. Additionally, the StopWatch could be started inside DoWork

Comment: I have added the code how i think it should look like (untested)